# How do I write a Windows batch script to copy the newest version of a file from all sub-directories of a directory?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I need to copy the newest version (modified date) of a specific file from all sub-directories of a directory. I'm using the following but it takes the file from the first sub-directory that is found in alphabetical order.

```
@echo off
set source="C:\copytest"
set target="C:\26Feb2016"

FOR /F "delims=" %%I IN ('DIR myfile.mp4 /S /B /T:W') DO COPY "%%I" %target% & echo %%I & GOTO :END
:END
```

Any responses will be appreciated!
Thanks.

Comment: Since you are looking for one specific file, how do you expect the second, third, etc. files to appear in the target directory since the second, etc. files would overwrite the first? And to fix your existing code, remove the `&goto end`.

Comment: look at `robocopy /?` - it will only copy new files by default and it can scan subdirectories.

Comment: I think Magoo's post has some important questions for you. If you are going to use `/T:W`, then a `/O:D` probably needs to be specified.